# How to get the index of an item inside a list on flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, indexing

Im trying to get the index of and item inside a list which is inside a **Column()** in flutter, how do I do that? I've tried making a var called index and set it to 0 and have it increment by each item that is build but it doesn't seem to work out and I don't know why.

And it can't be made with **ListView.builder()** because of some other reasons

My index var:

```
int index = 0;
```

My code:

```
                            markerPointers: _sortedList
                                .map(
                                  (data) => LinearWidgetPointer(
                                    value: data.points,
                                    position: LinearElementPosition.cross,
                                    animationDuration: 2000,
                                    offset: 500,
                                    child: UserCardWidget(
                                      data: data,
                                      index: index + 1,
                                      isExpandedMethod: _isExpanded,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                                .toList(),
```

Comment: change index: index + 1 to index++

Comment: yeap soon as I posted the question I tried doing that and it worked, but thx though.

Comment: @jim proposed you a correct solution. But remember that, on calling setState might cause the problems.

Comment: What do you mean and how would I resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `.asMap()` it will convert your list to a map with the keys equal to the index.

```
markerPointers: category._sortedList
                    .asMap()
                    .map(
                      (i, element) {
                        return MapEntry(
                          i,
                          LinearWidgetPointer(
                                value: data.points,
                                position: LinearElementPosition.cross,
                                animationDuration: 2000,
                                offset: 500,
                                child: UserCardWidget(
                                  data: data,
                                  index: i,
                                  isExpandedMethod: _isExpanded,
                                ),
                              ),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                    .values
                    .toList(),
```

Comment: when I try to do it this way it gives me this error: ```The return type 'LinearWidgetPointer' isn't a 'MapEntry<_, _>', as required by the closure's context.```

Comment: oh I removed some of the code while replacing it with your `LinearWidget`. anyway I edited the comment